# Changing states with nested views and a default nested state on page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have a Angular App with nested ui-views.
On the Main page  I have a sub menu with two links that render on the main page. I have Menu1 that displays a list and would like to have that list shown as default on page load. I also have Menu2 that displays a different list once clicked but is not the default view.

I've gotten the nested views to work slightly with errors. I can change only to one state on load and cannot change states back and forth. 
I'm getting  a 404 error after one of the nested views have been clicked, the other returns a 404 error.

Also how do I have a nested view render as the default view on load?
Like if I wanted menu1 to render in the ui-view as default when the main page is loaded.

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('/', {
    url: '/index',
    templateUrl: '/index',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
  })
  .state('/main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'main',
    controller:   'mainCtrl'
  })
  .state('/main.menu1', {
    url: '/menu1',
    templateUrl: "menu1",
    controller: 'menu1Ctrl'
  })
  .state('/main.menu2', {
    url: '/menu2',
    templateUrl: "menu2",
    controller: 'menu2Ctrl'
  });
```

**controllers**

```
app.controller('menu1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.livenow = [
    { name: 'user1',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user2',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user3',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user4',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user5',
    status: 'online'
    }
    ];
}]);
app.controller('menu2Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.livenow = [
{ name: 'user6',
    status: 'offline'
    },
    { name: 'user7',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user8',
    status: 'offline'
    },
    { name: 'user9',
    status: 'online'
    },
    { name: 'user10',
    status: 'offline'
    }
    ];
}]);
```

**main.html**

```
<div class="section2 col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section2nav col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
            <a ui-sref='/main.menu1'> menu1 </a> | <a ui-sref="/main.menu2"> menu2 </a>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try removing the slashes from all the `state`s. Name the root state "index" or something similar. I'm not entirely sure, but I've never seen anyone use slashes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the slash on each state. For example,

`.state('/main', {` should be `.state('main', {`